# Working with urls in fs-extra in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to use fs.createReadStream('./imageName.png'). But I don't have a image path, instead I have an url of an image. Now what all I need is to use the url and get the same response for both cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a request to access the image. You cannot handle the image as a local file as the image is stored in another location.

```
request(url).on('data',(data) => {
        try{
            let image = data;    
        }
        catch(error){
            callback("");
        }
        callback(image);
    });
```

If you want to use a Stream, you can add something like:

```
let reader = fs.createReadStream("img.png");
request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(reader);
reader.on('data' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. While printing the two responses(one from file path and another from url), these responses are varying. But I need the same response for the both cases

Comment: If you are using streams, try using pipes. `let reader = fs.createReadStream("img.png");
request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(reader);
reader.on...`